# Excel 2013 won't import into SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, import, import-from-excel

I've been having trouble because Excel 2013 won't import into SQL Server 2012.  I always have to convert the Excel to an older version such as 97-2003 to get it to work.

Does anyone know a workaround for this, or is this the only way?

I have SQL Server Management Studio 2012 with the Service Pack 1, and I have the latest Office 2013.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you trying to import it currently?

Comment: @PinnyM OP mentioned saving the excel into an older version (97-2003) and then importing the data, which works.

Comment: @Jerry, I mean what tool (command-line, SQL, or UI) and steps are being used to try and import the excel file - for the one that works (97-2003) and the one that doesn't (2013).

Comment: I am using the SQL Import and Export wizard.  The one that is installed alongside the Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the command line scripting in import wizard of SSMS. Remember SQL server 2012 by default excel supporting format is  .xlsx,.xlsm,.xlt.

There is another UI called SQL server Migration Assistant, which can help you do the same where the UI gives you option of selecting the format and command line script to default teh format.

Hope this answer clarifies you. Mark as answer if this helps.